Android: how to do a horizontal translation after a bitmap rotation?
I would like to draw a bitmap on a canvas with the method canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, null),
where I have to apply a transformation matrix to the bitmap.
Let's have a bitmap with a width of 500px and a height of 500px.
First, I rotate the bitmap by 45 degrees around its center, by calling the method matrix.preRotate(45, bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2); which gives this:

Then, I would like to translate the bitmap to the right, I want the bitmap to move "horizontally" 100px to the right, the expected result should be this :

So how can I do this with the matrix ?

You call translate on the matrix.  That moves everything relative to the axis without rotation, skew, or scaling it

If I call translate on matrix to translate bitmap on x axis , the bitmap won't move horizontally because the x axis was rotated before

The typical order of transformations is: first scale (S) then rotate (R) then translate (T).
This is usually abbreviated as T * R * S. Note that matrix multiplication works right to left like function composition.
Using the Matrix class you have 2 ways to do it:
val mat1 = Matrix().apply {
    preTranslate(1f, 1f)
    preRotate(45f)
    preScale(2f, 2f)
}

val mat2 = Matrix().apply {
    postScale(2f, 2f)
    postRotate(45f)
    postTranslate(1f, 1f)
}

assert(mat1 == mat2)

